# difference between resource discovery and service discovery

Tags: cloud, discovery, service-discovery

What is the difference between **resource discovery** and **service discovery** in the cloud computing?
Why is there no paper surveys for **resource discovery** in the cloud computing but for service discovery is a survey article?

Answer (score 2):

In the context of IoT, a physical device is represented by an **ENTITY**. This entity can be a human, an animal, a car, a store, an electric appliance. The **DEVICE** is attached to an **ENTITY** and is the hardware component. The software component that controls the **DEVICE** is a **RESOURCE**. As implementations of resources can vary in terms of platform, a **SERVICE** provides a well known - standardised interface, offering all the necessary functionalitites for interacting with entities and related processes.

**Resource discovery** defines the process necessary to discover all these software components from the physical world. Usually, each of these resources are offered as services to be used by cloud platforms. This is why in all the surveys, you will find **Service discovery**. The aim is to find a way to enable other users to use some physical devices and without necessarily being in the same location. Also, in terms of resource discovery it can be any number of ways of doing this. But ultimately, the aim is to find an uniform-standardised way of doing this.

[image: Relationship between resources and services]